# bitmap conversion delphi xe5

Tags: java, android, delphi, bitmap, firemonkey

i have a function that take android installed apps with their icons. That function extract the Jdrawable and convert it in Jbitmap (and for test this function i saved this jbitmap to file and all is ok) but if i try to convert this jbitmap to a Tbitmap i had access violation at this line:

**if Result.Map(TMapAccess.maWrite, BitmapData) then**

```
function JBitmapToBitmap(const AImage: JBitmap): TBitmap;
var
  ImageData: TJavaArray<Integer>;
  BitmapData: TBitmapData;
  Width, Height: Integer;
begin
  Assert(AImage <> nil);
  Width := AImage.getWidth;
  Height := AImage.getHeight;
  ImageData := TJavaArray<Integer>.Create(Width * Height);
  AImage.getPixels(ImageData, 0, Width, 0, 0, Width, Height);
  if Result.Map(TMapAccess.maWrite, BitmapData) then    <--- access violation
  try
    Result := TBitmap.Create(Width, Height);
    Move(ImageData.Data^, BitmapData.Data^, Width * Height * SizeOf(Integer));
  finally
    Result.Unmap(BitmapData);
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

I'm sure that the jBitmap isn't corrupted because if i save to file the Jbitmap, i can see it good.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create Result object before Map method call